# Average number of tosses to reach a head with a biased coin

Tags: probability, statistics

Given a biased coin with probability **P** of flipping to head position, how can I compute **N**, the average number of tosses for reaching a head?

I also need a formula for the reverse problem, computing **P** as a function of **N** (if I know the average number of tosses, how can I find the bias).

Edit: This can apparently be rephrased as computing the average number of Bernoulli trials with probability **P** to get a success. The result is **N = 1/p** according to [this article](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/LengthToFirstSuccess.shtml).

Comment: This has to do with the geometric distribution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer:

You could have H, TH, TTH, ....

P(H) = p

P(TH) = qp  where q = 1-p

P(TTH) = $q^2p$

...

Expected No of Tosses = $p+2pq+3pq^2+4pq^3+\cdots$

E = $p(1+2q+3q^2+4q^3+....)$

S = $(1+2q+3q^2+4q^3+....)$

qS = $q+2q^2+3q^3+....)$

S-qS = $1+q+q^2+q^3+\cdots$

S(1-q) = $\frac{1}{(1-q)}$

S = $\frac{1}{(1-q)^2}$

E =$\frac{p}{(1-q)^2}$

E = $\frac{1}{p}$

That will be your answer

Now if somebody gives you E, you calculate p

Thanks

Satish

Answer (score 1):

The distribution you are looking for is geometric distribution.
The probability of reaching head in k-th tossing is:
$$
P\left\{ {X = k} \right\} = p{(1 - p)^{k - 1}}\,\,\,k = 1,2,..., + \infty 
$$

and the p is what you mentioned in your question.

Mean of this random variable is:
$$
E\left\{ X \right\} = \frac{1}{p}
$$
So $N =\dfrac{1}{p} $.

With this relation the reverse problem has readily solved.