# Expected number of attempts to generate random binary sequence of length N containing at least x 1's

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, random

I'm generating random binary sequences of fixed length N

Example with N=10: 0101011100, this one has x=5 1's

How often do I have to generate such a sequence until I get one with at least x 1's on average?

The order or position of these 1's doesn't matter, only their number.

Here is a plot for N=100

[image]

Comment: Is parity specified for N ?

Comment: What do you mean by parity? If you mean whether it is known if it is odd or even: it can be both, any natural number

Comment: You are expected to first show what efforts you have made and where you are stuck, so please edit it in.

Comment: @trueblueanil I've searched for the right QA here on the site, and don't know how to approach the problem myself

Comment: Have you been taught the binomial distribution ?

Comment: can you work out the probability of a given random sequence being successful?

Comment: @ZoeAllen I could, see below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of possible binary sequences of length N is $ 2^n $

The number of ways k 1's can be ordered in a sequence of length N is $ C(N,k) $

So to get the number of ways k>=x 1's can be ordered we just add all k<x together and subtract that from the total number of possibilities:

$$ 2^n - \sum_{k=0}^{x-1} C(N,k) $$

To get the probability of getting one of these combinations in a single attempt, we divide this by the total number of sequences.

$$ p = \frac{2^n - \sum_{k=0}^{x-1} C(N,k)}{2^n} $$

The average number of tosses to reach a head with an unfair coin with success probability $ p $ is [apparently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666446/average-number-of-tosses-to-reach-a-head-with-a-biased-coin) just $ 1/p $ so we get

$$ expected = \frac{2^n}{2^n - \sum_{k=0}^{x-1} C(N,k)} $$

and this agrees with the simulation

[image]

and allows one to calculate and plot values beyond the ones that can be computed in reasonable time (here with a logarithmic y-axis because it grows so fast)

[image]